# Testing C++ Math functions with Python's C Extension - Precision issues

Tags: python, c++, numpy, testing, matrix

I wrote a C++ wrapper class to some functions in LAPACK. In order to test the class, I use the [Python C Extension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html), where I call `numpy`, and do the same operations, and compare the results by taking the difference

For example, for the inverse of a matrix, I generate a random matrix in C++, then pass it as a string (with many, many digits, like 30 digits) to Python's terminal using `PyRun_SimpleString`, and assign the matrix as `numpy.matrix(...,dtype=numpy.double)` (or `numpy.complex128`). Then I use `numpy.linalg.inv()` to calculate the inverse of the same matrix. Finally, I take the difference between `numpy`'s result and my result, and use [`numpy.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with a specific relative tolerance to see whether the results are close enough.

**The problem**: The problem is that when I use C++ floats, the relative precision I need to be able to compare is about `1e-2`!!! And yet with this relative precision I get some statistical failures (with low probability).

Doubles are fine... I can do `1e-10` and it's statistically safe.

While I know that floats have intrinsic bit precision of about `1e-6`, I'm wondering why I have to go so low to `1e-2` to be able to compare the results, and it still fails some times!

So, going so low down to `1e-2` got me wondering whether I'm thinking about this whole thing the wrong way. Is there something wrong with my approach?

Please ask for more details if you need it.

---

**Update 1**: Eric requested example of Python calls. Here is an example:

```
//create my matrices
Matrix<T> mat_d = RandomMatrix<T>(...);
auto mat_d_i = mat_d.getInverse();

//I store everything in the dict 'data'
PyRun_SimpleString(std::string("data={}").c_str());

//original matrix
//mat_d.asString(...) will return in the format [[1,2],[3,4]], where 32 is 32 digits per number
PyRun_SimpleString(std::string("data['a']=np.matrix(" + mat_d.asString(32,'[',']',',') + ",dtype=np.complex128)").c_str());
//pass the inverted matrix to Python
PyRun_SimpleString(std::string("data['b_c']=np.matrix(" + mat_d_i.asString(32,'[',']',',') + ",dtype=np.complex128)").c_str());
//inverse in numpy
PyRun_SimpleString(std::string("data['b_p']=np.linalg.inv(data['a'])").c_str());
//flatten the matrices to make comparing them easier (make them 1-dimensional)
PyRun_SimpleString("data['fb_p']=((data['b_p']).flatten().tolist())[0]");
PyRun_SimpleString("data['fb_c']=((data['b_c']).flatten().tolist())[0]");

//make the comparison. The function compare_floats(f1,f2,t) calls numpy.isclose(f1,f2,rtol=t)
//prec is an integer that takes its value from a template function, where I choose the precision I want based on type
PyRun_SimpleString(std::string("res=list(set([compare_floats(data['fb_p'][i],data['fb_c'][i],1e-"+ std::to_string(prec) +") for i in range(len(data['fb_p']))]))[0]").c_str());
//the set above eliminates repeated True and False. If all results are True, we expect that res=[True], otherwise, the test failed somewhere
PyRun_SimpleString(std::string("res = ((len(res) == 1) and res[0])").c_str());
//Now if res is True, then success
```

Comments in the code describe the procedure step-by-step.

Comment: Can you show us how you call `PyRun_SimpleString`, and show us an example of the string being passed to it? Why not use C++ `double`s instead of `float`s, given you're putting them in a double numpy array?

Comment: @Eric I added the code example. My matrix class supports operations on `float`s and `double`s (and their complex versions), and I need to test them all.

Comment: FWIW, you can combine all of your`PyRun_SimpleString` invocations into a single one, passing a string with line breaks.

Comment: What is `T`? `double`? `float`?

Comment: @Eric Anything... On doubles it's OK. On floats it's a problem (like I describe in the question). `prec` is an int that takes the value from a template function, where I choose the tolerance based on type (I'll add that note in the code up there).

Comment: It seems that your code is in essence doing `d = np.matrix(..., dtype=float32)`, `di1 = np.linalg.inv(i)` `di2 = np.linalg.inv(d.astype(np.float64))` `why_are_they_different(di1, di2)`. If you replace the `complex128` dtype with the type that maches `T`, do you get what you expect?

Comment: @Eric Yes, exactly. That's all it does. But I never cast to float32 in Python. I always use doubles or complex128 to avoid conversion precision problems, yet that doesn't help.

Comment: But the thing you passed to python is already a float32 that you cast in python back to a float64. That will cause python to give a more correct answer than your C++ code when `std::is_same<T, float>::value == true`.

Comment: @Eric I see your point. So you're saying that there's a large difference in precision because Python's way is more accurate than C++ (when C++ is using `float`). So you're saying if I cast my matrix to `float32` instead of `float64`, then the results will be close enough?

Comment: @Eric Thinking a little about your argument... shouldn't the results agree by `1e-6` anyway? They would disagree at a better precision level... Because there's 1 true answer, and floats will reach it by `1e-6`, and doubles with `1e-16`. Down to `1e-6` the results should be the same... right?

Comment: @Eric OK. I switched text types I pass to Python to be dependent on `std::is_same` with appropriate type to be `np.double` or `np.float32`, but didn't make any difference :-( ...

Comment: What is the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of your matrix?  (With numpy, you can find it with [`numpy.linalg.cond`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html).)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser So I measured this number for many matrix sizes by passing a matrix as an argument to `numpy.linalg.cond`. My findings are: 1. The resulting number doesn't depend on the size of the matrix. 2. The results are quite random and there's no correlation at all that I could identify. 3. The result ranges from 1 to a few tens of thousands. 4. There's no correlation between this number and failure. It could fail for small and large numbers. My quick observation is that it doesn't fail for very small numbers. (I haven't done super-duper statistics, let me know if I should).